# How to connect WinForms DataGridView to PostgreSQL DB over network

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms, connection-string, npgsql

I'm trying to set up a connection to a PostgreSQL database as a datasource for a WinForms DataGridView.

I can't figure out how to set up the connection.

I'm using DBeaver for my DBMS and have set up a test table with some simple data. Right now, I'm just trying to test the connection by sending the version to the console. The server is on a network and the host is an IP address.

In Form1_Load I've tried this:

```
string strConnString = "Server=<ipaddress>;Port=5432;Username=<username>;Password=<password>;Database=test.cars";
NpgsqlConnection objConn = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnString);

try
{
    objConn.Open();
    string strSelectCmd = "select version()";
    var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(strSelectCmd, objConn);
    var version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"PostgreSQL version: {version}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

But I get an exception at the `objConn.Open();` line.

The error in the message box says, "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

So, am I not setting up the connection string correctly? Once I get that connected, is the remainder of the code correct?

Comment: What's the specific exception on that line?

Comment: @Dortimer, see my addition to my question near the bottom.

Comment: Hmm, if you set a breakpoint in the catch block, are there any additional details in the exception object? Like an inner exception or a message on the root exception object for instance?

Comment: "test.cars". Is that supposed to be database.schema? I am not sure you can do that (never tried it that way myself). Try just with test. As a second point, whenever I have a problem with a connection, one of the first things to do, is to try telnet with the IP address and port. This guarantees that at least part of the connection string is ok. Have you checked this?

Comment: @Dortimer, I have a breakpoint at the Open() line. When I step into the catch line, this shows in the Output pane: "Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, I tried just "test" and got the same result. I'm not sure how to telnet to the IP address/port, but I'm getting assistance on that and will get back on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I needed FIPS disabled in the Group Policy Editor.